# Button firing twice when clicked

Tags: javascript

If you goto the JSFiddle underneath. Add two items and then press 'complete' on one of the items in the console it logs out the same button twice. I can't figure out why.

What am I doing wrong here! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/7k84p3oz/6/

HTML

```
    <input id="inputAdd" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button id="submitItem" type="button" name="button">Add</button>

    <!-- Start of list -->
    <ul id="listContent"></ul>
    <!-- End of list -->

    <!-- Start of completed -->
    <div id="completed">
        <h4>Completed</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- End of completed -->
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function() {
    var itemTracker = {
        // init
        init: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        // cacheDom
        cacheDom: {
            inputAdd: $('#inputAdd'),
            submitAdd: $('#submitItem'),
            listContent: $('#listContent'),
            completed: $('#completed')
        },

        // Add item
        addItem: function() {
            var itemValue = this.cacheDom.inputAdd.val();
            var listItem = $("<li></li>");
            var buttonRemove = '<button class="remove">Remove</button>';
            var buttonComplete = '<button class="complete">Complete</button>';
            listItem.append(itemValue);
            listItem.append(buttonRemove);
            listItem.append(buttonComplete);
            var itemContent = this.cacheDom.listContent.append(listItem);
            this.cacheDom.inputAdd.val("");

            // Remove item
            var remove = $('.remove');
            remove.on("click", function(e){
                $(e.target).closest("li").hide();
            });

            var complete = $(".complete");

            // Complete item
            var completedItem = function(e) {
                console.log(this);

                // var childParent = $(this).parent();
                // var rootParent = childParent.parent();
                // var parentId = rootParent.prop('id');
                //
                // if(parentId === "listContent") {
                //     $('#completed').append(listItem);
                // } else {
                //     $('#listContent').append(listItem);
                // }
            };
            complete.on("click", completedItem);
        },

        // Bind Events
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.cacheDom.submitAdd.on("click", this.addItem.bind(this));
        }
    };

    itemTracker.init();

})();

});
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I see only one log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every time you add a new item, you are getting **ALL** the buttons with class .complete `var complete = $(".complete");` and appending an action to them.

Hence, if you add 1 button: it will only trigger once.
If you add 2 buttons: the first one will trigger twice, the second one once.
If you add 3 button: the first one will trigger three times, the second twice and the third once.
etc...

You can fix it by replacing: `var complete = $(".complete");`
For: `var complete = $(listItem).find(".complete")`
On line 36.

This will ensure that it only selects the .complete button within the listItem that you are creating at that moment.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have bind the class name to click event; meaning the event handler is fired for number of HTML elements which has the class name *complete*.

Since you have *e* parameter in your event handler function try to use the e.target which will give the clicked element.

```
var completedItem = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you were using `var complete = $(".complete");`
 to find complete button. Due to this when you add second entry,  `$(".complete");` will return 2 elements and this will also attach event to the earlier node as well. 
What you can do wrap the complete button in jquery like

```
var buttonComplete = $('<button class="complete">Complete</button>')
```

and use this buttonComplete to attach click event.

```
buttonComplete.on("click", completedItem);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

(function() {
    var itemTracker = {
        // init
        init: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        // cacheDom
        cacheDom: {
            inputAdd: $('#inputAdd'),
            submitAdd: $('#submitItem'),
            listContent: $('#listContent'),
            completed: $('#completed')
        },

        // Add item
        addItem: function() {
          var index=this.cacheDom.listContent.children().length;
            var itemValue = this.cacheDom.inputAdd.val();
            var listItem = $("<li></li>");
            var buttonRemove = '<button class="remove">Remove</button>';
            var buttonComplete = $('<button class="complete">Complete</button>')
            listItem.append(itemValue);
            listItem.append(buttonRemove);
            listItem.append(buttonComplete);
            var itemContent = this.cacheDom.listContent.append(listItem);
            this.cacheDom.inputAdd.val("");

            // Remove item
            var remove = $('.remove');
            remove.on("click", function(e){
                $(e.target).closest("li").hide();
            });

            var complete = $(".complete");

            // Complete item
            var completedItem = function(e) {
                console.log(this);

                // var childParent = $(this).parent();
                // var rootParent = childParent.parent();
                // var parentId = rootParent.prop('id');
                //
                // if(parentId === "listContent") {
                //     $('#completed').append(listItem);
                // } else {
                //     $('#listContent').append(listItem);
                // }
            };
            buttonComplete.on("click", completedItem);
        },

        // Bind Events
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.cacheDom.submitAdd.on("click", this.addItem.bind(this));
        }
    };

    itemTracker.init();

})();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <input id="inputAdd" type="text" name="" value="">
        <button id="submitItem" type="button" name="button">Add</button>

        <!-- Start of list -->
        <ul id="listContent"></ul>
        <!-- End of list -->

        <!-- Start of completed -->
        <div id="completed">
            <h4>Completed</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- End of completed -->
```